# Scala: Is there any reason to prefer `filter+map` over `collect`?

Tags: scala

Can there be any reason to prefer `filter+map`:

```
list.filter (i => aCondition(i)).map(i => fun(i))
```

over `collect`? :

```
list.collect(case i if aCondition(i) => fun(i))
```

The one with `collect` (single look) looks faster and cleaner to me. So I would always go for `collect`.

Comment: I'm not sure performance would be much different.  They both traverse the full sequence once, and apply the predicate function only to the items that satisfy the condition, so they're both doing the same base amount of work.  It really comes down to how smart the compiler is, how big the sequence is, and how expensive the condition and function are to execute.

Comment: Though I suppose that the second one might allocate one less sequence, since it needn't trouble itself with the return from the `filter` call.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I think that's the main debate. Is it true that the second one allocates one less sequence (and hence more efficient)?

Comment: The reason would be the same as to prefer `map+flatten` over `flatMap` ...

Answer (score 65):

Most of Scala's collections eagerly apply operations and (unless you're using a macro library that does this for you) will not fuse operations.  So `filter` followed by `map` will usually create two collections (and even if you use `Iterator` or somesuch, the intermediate form will be transiently created, albeit only an element at a time), whereas `collect` will not.

On the other hand, `collect` uses a partial function to implement the joint test, and partial functions are slower than predicates (`A => Boolean`) at testing whether something is in the collection.

Additionally, there can be cases where it is simply clearer to read one than the other and you don't care about performance or memory usage differences of a factor of 2 or so.  In that case, use whichever is clearer.  Generally if you already have the functions named, it's clearer to read

```
xs.filter(p).map(f)
xs.collect{ case x if p(x) => f(x) }
```

but if you are supplying the closures inline, `collect` generally looks cleaner

```
xs.filter(x < foo(x, x)).map(x => bar(x, x))
xs.collect{ case x if foo(x, x) => bar(x, x) }
```

even though it's not necessarily shorter, because you only refer to the variable once.

Now, how big is the difference in performance?  That varies, but if we consider a a collection like this:

```
val v = Vector.tabulate(10000)(i => ((i%100).toString, (i%7).toString))
```

and you want to pick out the second entry based on filtering the first (so the filter and map operations are both really easy), then we get the following table.

Note: one can get lazy views into collections and gather operations there.  You don't always get your original type back, but you can always use `to` get the right collection type.  So `xs.view.filter(p).map(f).toVector` would, because of the view, not create an intermediate.  That is tested below also.  It has also been suggested that one can `xs.flatMap(x => if (p(x)) Some(f(x)) else None)` and that this is *efficient*.  **That is not so.**   It's also tested below.  And one can avoid the partial function by explicitly creating a builder:  `val vb = Vector.newBuilder[String]; xs.foreach(x => if (p(x)) vb += f(x)); vb.result`, and the results for that are also listed below.

In the table below, three conditions have been tested: filter out nothing, filter out half, filter out everything.  The times have been normalized to filter/map (100% = same time as filter/map, lower is better).  Error bounds are around +- 3%.

**Performance of different filter/map alternatives**

```
====================== Vector ========================
filter/map   collect  view filt/map  flatMap   builder
   100%        44%          64%        440%      30%    filter out none
   100%        60%          76%        605%      42%    filter out half
   100%       112%         103%       1300%      74%    filter out all
```

Thus, `filter/map` and `collect` are generally pretty close (with `collect` winning when you keep a lot), `flatMap` is far slower under all situations, and creating a builder always wins.  (This is true *specifically for `Vector`*.  Other collections may have somewhat different characteristics, but the trends for most will be similar because the differences in operations are similar.)  Views in *this* test tend to be a win, but they don't always work seamlessly (and they aren't really better than `collect` except for the empty case).

So, bottom line: prefer `filter` then `map` if it aids clarity when speed doesn't matter, or prefer it for speed when you're filtering out almost everything but still want to keep things functional (so don't want to use a builder); and otherwise use `collect`.

Comment: By "filter none" you mean "filter out none", not "filter catches/retains none". The first code sample opines "it's clearer to read [filter and map]". It's great to see such a detailed answer from north of 100K rep.

Comment: Would be interesting to see how adding `.view` before the `filter` changes things.

Comment: An additional consideration in favor of `collect` is code reuse. The PF may be more clearly reusable than the individual predicate and mapper functions.

Comment: @IgorUrisman - It's rare in practice to re-use partial functions, so I would say the opposite is more likely: that predicate and mapper functions are more likely to be reusable.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is rather opinion based, but given the following definitions:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3,4)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> def f(x: Int) = 2*x
f: (x: Int)Int

scala> def p(x: Int) = x%2 == 0
p: (x: Int)Boolean
```

Which of the two do you find nicer to read:

```
l.filter(p).map(f)
```

or

```
l.collect{ case i if p(i) => f(i) }
```

(Note that I had to fix your syntax above, as you need the bracket and `case` to add the `if` condition).

I personally find the `filter`+`map` much nicer to read and understand. It's all a matter of the exact syntax that you use, but given `p` and `f`, you don't have to write anonymous functions when using `filter` or `map`, while you do need them when using collect.

You also have the possibility to use `flatMap`:

```
l.flatMap(i => if(p(i)) Some(f(i)) else None)
```

Which is likely to be the most efficient among the 3 solutions, but I find it less nice than `map` and `filter`.

Overall, it's very difficult to say which one would be faster, as it depends a lot of which optimizations end up being performed by `scalac` and then the JVM. All 3 should be pretty close, and definitely not a factor in deciding which one to use.

Comment: So why this argument is not correct: "collect" is just like one single loop, "filter+map" is like two consequence loops. Hence (efficiency-wise) one should prefer "collect". Am I missing anything. (and good thing you mentioned the 3rd alternative.)

Comment: It's not fair to compare to Rex "Mr Collections" Kerr, but nobody would expect the flatMap to be more efficient. My personal peeve is using ell as a var name because it looks like one. Now, that is opinion-based!

Answer (score 0):

One case where `filter/map` looks cleaner is when you want to flatten the result of filter

```
def getList(x: Int) = {
  List.range(x, 0, -1)
}

val xs = List(1,2,3,4)

//Using filter and flatMap
xs.filter(_ % 2 == 0).flatMap(getList)

//Using collect and flatten
xs.collect{ case x if x % 2 == 0 => getList(x)}.flatten
```

Comment: Sometimes with `flatMap` you don't need `filter`: `xs.flatMap(n=> if (n%2<1) getList(n) else List())`