# skip the bad element rather than throws scala.MatchError

Tags: scala

Given the following code，it will throw `scala.MatchError` because `"Hello"` doesn't match the case statement.

What I want is that when `map` encounters an element that doesn't match the case statement, it doesn't throw exception but simply skip it, so that the result `data2` will only contain elements that pass the `map`

I would ask how to achieve this functionality

```
  def testCaseMatch(): Unit = {
    val data = List((1, 2), (3, 4), "Hello")
    val data2 = data.map {
      case (x, y) => x + " " + y
    }
    println(data2)
}
```

Also, I have seen many code are following the above pattern, but the case state doesn't help much because it throws exception if the case fails. I would ask why people would use this pattern in their code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `filter` the elements you want to operate on,

```
scala> val data = List((1, 2), (3, 4), "Hello")
data: List[java.io.Serializable] = List((1,2), (3,4), Hello)

scala> data.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Tuple2[Int, Int]]).map {case(a, b) => s"$a $b"}
res5: List[String] = List(1 2, 3 4)
```

which is same as `collect`,

```
scala> data.collect {case(a, b) => s"$a $b"}
res6: List[String] = List(1 2, 3 4)
```

Reference

[Scala: Can there be any reason to prefer `filter+map` over `collect`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36962581/432903)

Answer (score 1):

Use `collect` instead of `map`:

```
val data = List((1, 2), (3, 4), "Hello")
val data2 = data.collect {
  case (x, y) => x + " " + y
}
println(data2) // List(1 2, 3 4)
```