# Returning the second number of pairs by filtering the first number

Tags: scala

Lets say I have pairs (1,2),(3, 9), (5, 6), (7,3), (9, 10)

I want to return a list of the second part of the pair when the first part is greater than 4.

So in the given example, I would return (6, 3, 10).

Well what I've done is filter out the terms but don't know how to get the second parts.

lets say `a` is the pair of sequence

```
a.filter(x=>x._1 > 4) // this filters out the pairs.. now i dont know how to cascade to return the second part as in x._2
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: As I always say the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) is your friend. Also, it would be good to follow any basic tutorial, functions like `map` are going to be your day to day and even if they are very simple without knowing them **Scala** can become pretty hard to write.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` to apply a function to each element of the collection. So here, you could use `.map(x => x._2)` to get the second part of each element.

In total, you'd use: `a.filter(x => x._1 > 4).map(x => x._2)`

Comment: Generally, `filter` + `.map` = `.collect`

Comment: Or even better use `collect` to apply both steps in one: `data.collect { case (key, value) if (key > 4) => value }` - this also improves readability of the code since it is better to name the components of the tuples instead of using `._1` and `._2`

Comment: Ahh, yes, it seems that using `.collect` is the more idiomatic way of doing a `filter`+`map`. There is some discussion about it in this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961777/scala-can-there-be-any-reason-to-prefer-filtermap-over-collect

Comment: Use view and do filter and map. It’s pretty much the same performance as collect and it’s subjectively clearer